# CardsLib listview not getting populated

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardslib

I am using [Cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) and am trying to populate each card with an custom layout.

I have everything set up but I cannot seem to get this to work. The problem I am having is that the CardListView doesn't get populated.

Here's my codes:

```
public class ThemeActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_theme);

    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        ColorCard card = new ColorCard(this);

        switch (i) {
        case 0:

            card.mTitle = "Default Theme";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.defaulttheme_thumb;

            break;
        case 1:

            card.mTitle = "Cool Blue";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.theme1_thumb;

            break;
        case 2:

            card.mTitle = "Tropic Red";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.theme2_thumb;

            break;
        case 3:

            card.mTitle = "Distant Road";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.theme3_thumb;

            break;
        case 4:

            card.mTitle = "Simplistic";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.theme4_thumb;

            break;

        case 5:

            card.mTitle = "Coffe Time";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.theme5_thumb;

            break;

        case 6:

            card.mTitle = "Gloomy Orange";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.theme6_thumb;

            break;
        case 7:
            card.mTitle = "Dappled Purple";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.theme7_thumb;

            break;

        case 8:

            card.mTitle = "Vibrant Green";
            card.imageId = R.drawable.theme8_thumb;

            break;

        }

        cards.add(card);

    }

    CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(this, cards);

    CardListView listView = (CardListView) this.findViewById(R.id.myList);
    if (listView != null) {
        listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
    }

}
}
```

Custom card class:

```
public class ColorCard extends Card {

protected String mTitle;
protected int imageId;
TextView themeName;
ImageView themeThumb;

protected int count;

public ColorCard(Context context) {
    this(context, R.layout.layout_cardview);
}

public ColorCard(Context context, int innerLayout) {
    super(context, innerLayout);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    // Add ClickListener
    setOnClickListener(new OnCardClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click Listener card=" + count,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {

    // Retrieve elements
    themeName = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.themeText);

    themeThumb = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.themeThumb);

    if (themeName != null)
        themeName.setText(mTitle);

    if (themeThumb != null)
        themeThumb.setImageResource(imageId);

}



 }
```

Here are my layouts:

Main CardListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
    android:id="@+id/myList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card:list_card_layout_resourceID="@layout/layout_cardview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout_cardview

```
    <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/list_cardId"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/row_card" />
```

row_card:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/themeThumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/themeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         />

     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `card:card_layout_resourceID` defined in the `CardViewNative` should define the global layout of the card.

It should be something like this:

```
card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/native_card_thumbnail_layout"
```

Check [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDLIST.md#use-your-custom-layout-for-each-row) for more info.

You are using (`@layout/row_card`) a inner-layout. Check [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/OVERVIEW.md) for more info.